# why do i get NONE in list?

Tags: python, list

Consider this LIST:

```
test = ["stas", "doug", "saman", "movie"]
for q in range(len(test)):
    PreGroup = None
    if (q > 0):
        PreGroup = test[q-1]
    print PreGroup
```

How can i get rid of NONE? as the FIRST output?
i need to have the q-1 set there, or at least i think, because i need to have PreGroup to be one Index BEFORE the current.

my PreGroup must not have None, since i am passing it later in my code, and if it gets NONE, i get an error.

Thanks.

Comment: You could probably get more useful advice if you explain the context of why you want to do this.

Answer (score 1):

`range` starts at `0`, so the first time through the test `if (q > 0)` fails, and `PreGroup` stays at `None`.

As a side note, you don't need parenthesis around the `if` test.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to set `PreGroup` (to something other than None) if `q` is 0. That's fine, but then you print the value of `PreGroup` whether it has been set or not. If you put the `print` inside the `if` as well, it will only print if `PreGroup` has been set to `test[q-1]`. You can then also remove the `PreGroup = None` line because `PreGroup` doesn't need to exist outside of the `if`.

An even better way to solve your problem though, would be to simply let the loop start at 1 instead of 0. That way you don't have to even check whether `q` is 0. You can do that by using `range(1, len(test))`.

Answer (score 1):

You're not expressing very clearly what it is that you want, but I suppose what you're saying is that you want both a valid current group `test[q]` and a valid previous group `test[q-1]` during every iteration of the loop. In that case, you could use `range(1, len(test))` to make `q` start at `1` rather than `0`.

Alternatively, you could do this without using any index with this loop:

```
for (pre_group, group) in zip(test, test[1:]):
    print pre_group, group
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe something like this

```
test = ["stas", "doug", "saman", "movie"]
for q in test:
    PreGroup = None
    q = test.index(q)
    if q > 0:
        PreGroup = test[q]
    print PreGroup
```

Comment: This code will still print None on the first iteration. Furthermore it will now behave differently as it will print the current object on each iteration (other than the first) instead of the previous one. And you've increased the running time from linear to quadratic by using `index`.